# Typescript why is my Get request comming in as Camel case?

Tags: c#, angular, typescript

I'm making a `GET` request from my `Angular 8 and typescript` app to an `ASP.NET CORE 3 web API` App. The object returned is in camel case, I'd like to to stay in Pascal Case.

It looks like this in TypeScript

```
    this.httpClient.get<Task>("Task/GetTask/" + task.id).subscribe((ganttTask: Task) => {

        console.log(ganttTask);
    });
```

Here is the task Object in TS

```
export class Task{
    public TaskID: string;
    public SubprojectID: string;
    public Description: string;
    public Color: string;
    public SortOrder: number;
    public WbsColor: string;
    public TextColor: string;
    public StartDate: Date;
    public DurationHours: Number;
    public EndDate: Date;
    public PlannedStartDate: Date;
    public PlannedEndDate: Date;

    constructor(){
        //default colors
        this.Color = '#ABD8E6'; 
        this.TextColor = '#000000';
        this.WbsColor = '#000000';
    }
}
```

Here is the task object in C#

```
public class Task
    {
        public Task() {

        }

        [Key]
        public Guid TaskID {get;set;}
        public Guid SubprojectID { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset StartDate { get; set; }
        public int DurationHours { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset EndDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? PlannedStartDate { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset? PlannedEndDate { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Color { get; set; }
        public string TextColor { get; set; }
        public string WbsColor { get; set; }
        public int SortOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

Here is an example of the returned data

```
{

    color: "#ed0732"
    description: "test 4"
    durationHours: 4
    endDate: "2019-11-04T22:00:00+00:00"
    plannedEndDate: null
    plannedStartDate: null
    sortOrder: 0
    startDate: "2019-11-04T12:00:00+00:00"
    subprojectID: "c9335b34-8b2d-42de-8cad-ba0ca1a79a5d"
    taskID: "e9cef6f6-82a8-4f9c-9fda-692f2a84cd24"
    textColor: "#f7dcf7"
    wbsColor: "#000000" 
  }
```

This only happens to this entity, I'm guessing it's because the dates are returned as strings. This `Task` object is going to grow to have around 100 properties. I'd rather not have to transform this or any other object with this many properties unless I have to. Is there a way to Map the returned type to the Task object? Should I change the way I'm working with the dates?

Comment: Your jsonSerializer will convert to camel case you need to configure the jsonSerialization in C#, you haven't provided what type of project you;re using OWIN, .net-core, global asax? if you want an accurate answer show how you're configuring your json or show us what project you're using

Comment: You're right, I didn't realize that. I thought I already had it configured. Thanks. I'd be happy to accept this if you put it in an answer.

Comment: thanks I'll post it in a second

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your jsonSerializer will convert to camel case you need to configure the jsonSerialization in C#.

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
//Set to use which ever resolver you need e.g pascal resolver;
settings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver();
```

Answer (score 1):

You may consider configuring your jsonSerializer to use camel case while conversation.